# Having some problems with a json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
exports.equipp = function(user, User, msg) {

    var itemname = msg.content.slice(8);

    User.find({id: user.id}, function(err, usser) {

        for(i = 0; i < usser[0].inventory.length; i++) {

            if (usser[0].inventory[i].name == itemname) {


                var Item = usser[0].inventory[i];

                for (j = 0; j < usser[0].equipped.length; j++) {

                    if (Item.type == usser[0].equipped[j].type) {

                    }
                    if (j == usser[0].equipped.length -1) {

                    }
                }
            } else {

                if (i == usser[0].inventory.length -1) {

                    msg.reply("You dont have that Item");

                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

I'm having some porblems with it at the end at the `if (j == usser[0].equipped.length -1)` it never goes through and hence never adds an item to a empty inventory. I have items which atm only contain Name, Dmg, and Type im checking if the types match then if they do i add the item to the equipped array and remove it from the items array and vice versa for the item already equipped and when there is no item with that type in the array i need to just add it and remvoe it from the other array but my code fails at the point stated above an array of json objects {
            "type": "Healm",
            "armor": 4,
            "name": "Starter Healm"
        },

Comment: Please read the usage description of the `json` tag: this question is not related to JSON.

Comment: ah sorry forgot to include that piece of information my arrays are in json let me edit that in @trincot

Comment: Your code example is very long and hard to parse, making it unlikely that you will get a good answer. You should try cutting it down into something easy to read and reproduce, so people can more easily find out what your issue is.

Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @PedroCastilho I removed most of the code not invloving the issue im having

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this :

```
    for(i = 0; i < usser[0].inventory.length; i++) {
        if (usser[0].inventory[i].name == itemname) {
            var Item = usser[0].inventory[i];
            // rest of code ...
        } else {
            if (i == usser[0].inventory.length -1) {
                msg.reply("You dont have that Item");
            }
        }
    }
```

Do:

```
    for(i = 0; i < usser[0].inventory.length; i++) {
        if (usser[0].inventory[i].name == itemname) {
            var Item = usser[0].inventory[i];
            // rest of code ...
        }
    }
    if (!Item) {
        msg.reply("You dont have that Item");
    }
```

The determining factor whether you found the item is that you have defined `Item`. It *after* the loop you find that `Item` was not set, you know the item was not in the list. This obviously also works when the list is empty.